# Python 3 - How to remove blank lines from command line app

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment for my Beginning Python class.  The assignment is fairly simple, receive the first name, last name, address line 1, address line 2, city, state, zip and print it out but only print address line 2 if it contains information, otherwise skip it.  I worked out some code to make it work, but the problem is that when it prints the information if there is no data in address line 2 the console shows a blank line.  then prints the city, state, and zip on the next line.  this is an online class at school so i'm basically teaching myself and just winging it as i go.  i would appreciate any help y'all can give me.

```
title = "Address Application"
print(title)

def main():
    global fname
    global lname
    global address1
    global address2
    global city
    global state
    global zip
    fname = input("Enter your first name: ")
    lname = input("Enter your last name: ")
    address1 = input("Enter your street address: ")
    address2 = input("If you had an additional address line, enter: ")
    city = input("Enter your city: ")
    state = input("Enter your 2 letter state abbreviation: ")
    while len(state) != 2:
        state = input("Please enter the 2 letter state abbreviation: ")
        if len(state) ==2:
            break

    zip = input("Enter your zip code: ")
    beautify()

# This function cleans up the user's input and outputs with proper capitalization
def beautify():
    fname_cap = fname.capitalize()
    lname_cap = lname.capitalize()
    address1_cap = address1.title()
    address2_cap = address2.title()
    city_cap = city.capitalize()
    state_cap = state.upper()
    print("=" * 80)
    print(fname_cap, lname_cap)
    print(address1_cap)
    if address2_cap != None:
        print(address2_cap)
    print(city_cap,",", state_cap, zip)
    print("=" * 80)
    end()

def end():
    end_result = input("Would you like to enter another address? Y or N ")
    if end_result.lower() == "n":
        exit()
    else:
        print()
        print("*" * 80)
        main()

main()
```

[image]

Comment: You should learn how to pass arguments into functions, and `return` variables back from them. Tagging everything as `global` is a hack to working around actual flow control.

Comment: will do.  i am only on day 3 of class, so i will try and figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user does not input the `address2`, the value of `address2` is an **empty string** rather than **None**. And so, you see the blank.

Hence, try

```
if address2_cap != '':
        print(address2_cap)
```

instead

```
if address2_cap != None:
        print(address2_cap)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title = "Address Application"
print(title)

def main():
    global fname
    global lname
    gLobal address1
    global address2
    global city
    global state
    global zip
    fname = input("Enter your first name: ")
    lname = input("Enter your last name: ")
    address1 = input("Enter your street address: ")
    address2 = input("If you had an additional address line, enter: ")
    city = input("Enter your city: ")
    state = input("Enter your 2 letter state abbreviation: ")
    while len(state) != 2:
        state = input("Please enter the 2 letter state abbreviation: ")
        if len(state) ==2:
            break

    zip = input("Enter your zip code: ")
    beautify()
```

This function cleans up the user's input and outputs with proper capitalization

```
def beautify():
    fname_cap = fname.capitalize()
    lname_cap = lname.capitalize()
    address1_cap = address1.title()
    address2_cap = address2.title()
    city_cap = city.capitalize()
    state_cap = state.upper()
    print("=" * 80)
    print(fname_cap, lname_cap)
    print(address1_cap)
    if (len(address2_cap) != 0):
        print(address2_cap)
    print(city_cap,",", state_cap, zip)
    print("=" * 80)
    end()

def end():
    end_result = input("Would you like to enter another address? Y or N ")
    if end_result.lower() == "n":
        exit()
    else:
        print()
        print("*" * 80)
        main()
```

main()

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I saw Nafiz's answer first, so tried to give you an upvote for helping, but I guess since i'm still new, it doesn't show the upvote on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a truthy check for `address2`, e.g. `if address2` rather than `if address2 != None`.

I'd also suggest avoiding the use of `global` and having fewer variables in general.

```
def main():
    print("Address Application")
    fname = input("Enter your first name: ")
    lname = input("Enter your last name: ")
    address1 = input("Enter your street address: ")
    address2 = input("If you had an additional address line, enter: ")
    city = input("Enter your city: ")
    state = ""
    while len(state) != 2:
        state = input("Please enter the 2 letter state abbreviation: ")
    zip_code = input("Enter your zip code: ")
    beautify(
        fname,
        lname,
        address1,
        address2,
        city,
        state,
        zip_code
    )
    if should_repeat():
        main()


def beautify(
    fname,
    lname,
    address1,
    address2,
    city,
    state,
    zip_code
):
    """
    This function cleans up the user's input and pretty-prints it
    """
    print("=" * 80)
    print(fname.capitalize(), lname.capitalize())
    print(address1.title())
    if address2:
        print(address2.title())
    print(f"{city.capitalize()}, {state.upper()} {zip_code}")
    print("=" * 80)


def should_repeat():
    if input(
        "Would you like to enter another address? Y or N "
    ).lower() == "n":
        return False
    print()
    print("*" * 80)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for the advice!  that code is definitely a lot cleaning looking that what i had.  i did figure out the passing variables (arguments?) into other functions bit after i posted this based on Corey's comment above.  

what does the "if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()" do?  i keep accidentally coming upon that bit in my IDE by autocomplete but i didn't know what it does.

Comment: For right now it doesn't make a difference, but you will absolutely need to do this with your top level code once you have projects with more than one file in them, so it's a good habit to get into.  :)